# Mysql query with recursive self JOIN

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query with a recursive self join. My tables are something as below:

Table1

```
EMP_ID      Name
1          Manger1 
2          Manger2
3          Manger3
4          Employ1
5          Employ2
```

Table2

```
Par_EMP_ID   EMP_ID   
1                2
2                3
3                4
3                5
```

Here in above tables the `Manager1`, `Manager2`, ..., `Employe2` are employees in a company where `Manager1` is Head of Dept. `Manager2` is reporting to `Manager1`, `Manager3` is reporting to `Manager2`, this relation ship is maintained in `table2` where `Par_EMP_ID` is `EMP_ID` of reportii and column `EMP_ID` is id of reporter. Now I want result as below:

```
Manager1      Manager2   Manager3  Employe1
Manager1      Manager2   Manager3  Employe2
```

Comment: Read [mysql how to find the total number of child rows with respect to a parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737784/mysql-how-to-find-the-total-number-of-child-rows-with-respect-to-a-parent/13737946#13737946)

Comment: Create your table here: http://sqlfiddle.com/ and call me.

Comment: And read [MySQL: Tree-Hierarchical query](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30021/mysql-tree-hierarchical-query)

Comment: You try my answer and comment if it doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

According to your specs, here's the solution:

```
SELECT  e.names member, d.name child
    FROM MEMBERS d INNER JOIN
        (SELECT a.id, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) NAMES
            FROM MEMBERS a
    INNER JOIN RELATIONSHIP b ON a.id = b.MEM_ID
INNER JOIN MEMBERS c ON c.id = b.PAR_MEM_ID
GROUP BY a.id) e ON e.id = d.id
```

Result:

```
|             MEMBER |        CHILD |
|--------------------|--------------|
| Great Grand Father | Grand Father |
|       Grand Father |       Father |
|             Father |       Child1 |
|             Father |       Child2 |
```

Note:the results may depend on your sample data. And I updated also the SQLFiddle below so you might want to check that out.

Here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63fb5/1).

Comment: Nice answer. What if I only wanted to see if there was a relationship chain between `Child2` and `Great Grand Father`? (Rather than every relationship?)

Comment: @Xeoncross got any answer