# MySQL Query with recursive self join to obtain full structure of results

Tags: mysql, join, recursive-query

I'm trying to create a query which will obtain the full transaction history of accounts in our database. The relationship is fairly simple, 'loanaccount' joins to 'loantransactions', and I can see the full history of that account.

However, some accounts will be refinanced or rescheduled, and for the full loan transaction history, I also need to link to the prior accounts. When completing a refinance/reschedule, the system creates a 'Transfer' activity on both the old and the new account, and I have been exploring this as a way to link them.

My attempts have largely related to using the parenttransactionkey in the transaction table - this is a foreign key back to the transaction table which links the two 'Transfer' activities which have been created. For example:

```
select
la.id,
la2.id

from loanaccount la
join loantransaction lt on lt.PARENTACCOUNTKEY = la.ENCODEDKEY
join loantransaction lt2 on lt2.PARENTLOANTRANSACTIONKEY = lt.ENCODEDKEY
join loanaccount la2 on lt2.PARENTACCOUNTKEY = la2.ENCODEDKEY

Where 
lt.type = 'TRANSFER'
```

In the above example, la.id would give me the new account ID, la2.id would give me the old account ID. There can be any number of previous accounts and I'm not sure how I can arrive at a solution which will continue to join to the nth level - as this only appears to work if there is a 1 new account and 1 old account.

To give a thorough example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
loanaccount
encodedkey     id         accountstate
a1a1a1         a1         active
b2b2b2         b2         closed
c3c3c3         c3         active
d4d4d4         d4         closed
e5e5e5         e5         closed

CREATE TABLE `loanaccount` (
`encodedkey` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
`id` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
`accountstate` VARCHAR(32),
 PRIMARY KEY (`encodedkey`));
 INSERT INTO ``loanaccount` (`encodedkey`, `id`) VALUES ('a1a1a1','a1','active'),'b2b2b2', 'b2','closed'),('c3c3c3', 'c3','active'),('d4d4d4','d4','closed'),('e5e5e5','e5','closed');



loantransaction
encodedkey   parentaccountkey   amount   type      entrydate   parentloantransactionkey
tra1         a1a1a1             1000     Interest  2017-12-31  null
tra2         a1a1a1             5000     Repayment 2017-12-01  null          
tra3         a1a1a1             50000    Transfer  2017-11-15  null          
tra4         b2b2b2             50000    Transfer  2017-11-15  tra3          
tra5         b2b2b2             900      Interest  2017-10-30  null
tra6         b2b2b2             5000     Repayment 2017-10-01  null  
tra7         b2b2b2             60000    Transfer  2017-09-15  null          
tra8         d4d4d4             60000    Transfer  2017-09-15  tra7   
tra9         d4d4d4             800      Interest  2017-09-30  null       
tra10        c3c3c3             7500     Repayment 2018-01-31  null       
tra11        c3c3c3             750000   Transfer  2018-01-01  null          
tra12        e5e5e5             750000   Transfer  2018-01-01  tra11 
tra13        e5e5e5             10000    Interest  2017-12-01  null    

CREATE TABLE `loantransaction` (
`encodedkey` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
`parentaccountkey` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
`amount` DECIMAL(18,2) NULL,
`type` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
`entrydate` DATE NOT NULL
`parentloantransactionkey` VARCHAR(32) NULL),
PRIMARY KEY (`encodedkey`));

INSERT INTO loantransaction (encodedkey, parentaccountkey, amount, type, entrydate, parentloantransactionkey) VALUES ('tra1', 'a1a1a1', '1000', 'Interest', '2017-12-31', ''),('tra2', 'a1a1a1', '5000', 'Repayment', '2017-12-01', ''),('tra3', 'a1a1a1', '50000', 'Transfer', '2017-11-15', ''),('tra4', 'b2b2b2', '50000', 'Transfer', '2017-11-15', 'tra3'),('tra5', 'b2b2b2', '900', 'Interest', '2017-10-30', ''),('tra6', 'b2b2b2', '5000', 'Repayment', '2017-10-01', ''),('tra7', 'b2b2b2', '60000', 'Transfer', '2017-09-15', ''),('tra8', 'd4d4d4', '60000', 'Transfer', '2017-09-15', 'tra7'),('tra9', 'd4d4d4', '800', 'Interest', '2017-09-30', ''),('tra10', 'c3c3c3', '7500', 'Repayment', '2018-01-31', ''),('tra11', 'c3c3c3', '75000', 'Transfer', '2018-01-01', ''),('tra12', 'e5e5e5', '75000', 'Transfer', '2018-01-01', 'tra11'),('tra13', 'e5e5e5', '10000', 'Interest', '2017-12-01', '')
```

So, I want to have a query which will give me the full transaction history of the active account. So for account ID a1 I would like to see the following:

```
loanaccount.id encodedkey   parentaccountkey   amount   type      entrydate   parentloantransactionkey
a1             tra1         a1a1a1             1000     Interest  2017-12-31  null
a1             tra2         a1a1a1             5000     Repayment 2017-12-01  null          
a1             tra3         a1a1a1             50000    Transfer  2017-11-15  null          
a1             tra4         b2b2b2             50000    Transfer  2017-11-15  tra3          
a1             tra5         b2b2b2             900      Interest  2017-10-30  null
a1             tra6         b2b2b2             5000     Repayment 2017-10-01  null  
a1             tra7         b2b2b2             60000    Transfer  2017-09-15  null          
a1             tra8         d4d4d4             60000    Transfer  2017-09-15  tra7   
a1             tra9         d4d4d4             800      Interest  2017-09-30  null
```

and for account ID c3 I should see:

```
loanaccount.id encodedkey   parentaccountkey   amount   type      entrydate   parentloantransactionkey    
c3             tra10        c3c3c3             7500     Repayment 2018-01-31  null       
c3             tra11        c3c3c3             750000   Transfer  2018-01-01  null          
c3             tra12        e5e5e5             750000   Transfer  2018-01-01  tra11 
c3             tra13        e5e5e5             10000    Interest  2017-12-01  null
```

My research shows I may need to create a procedure to complete this as shown in the following link:

[Mysql query with recursive self JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243690/mysql-query-with-recursive-self-join)

Ideally i'd like to avoid the procedure route - is there any way i can create a temporary table to achieve this?

Apologies for the lengthy post, and thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: MySQL 8.0  has recursive cte. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive otherwise go with procedure route.

Comment: The DB the data is held in is 5.7.19 - it's a suppliers system, so I have no control over the version unfortunately.

Comment: Then go for the function. Like this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30021/mysql-tree-hierarchical-query